# Git revert to old commit in remote

Tags: git, git-bash

I want to revert code to an older commit in my remote repo's master branch. But the problem is I do not have administrator rights to directly commit/push anything to the master branch. All I can do is create a new branch from master, do my changes there and then merge it with a pull request to master.

I took a new branch from master, reverted the code to where I wanted but when I try to merge it back to master it says no differences found.

I did the below to revert the code in branch and the revert happens exactly how I want

```
git reset --hard <commit>
git push --force
```

How can I merge these changes to master? Is there any other way by which I can revert the code in master?

Comment: Are you sure you branched from an updated master? You may be comparing a modified or out of date local copy. Try pulling master first. You may also need to delete your local master and fetch the remote again.

Comment: Yes I did, infact I branched out twice from the master, reverted it using the code I just pasted above and then when I raised a PR, it says no differences found.

Comment: The commands you show there don't tell the whole story, so we're left to speculate what you did. Also add your branching and commit commands.

Comment: If you went back in time in your new branch, don't expect the merge to master to pick up new changes, since it has *more* than your branch. Merging is not syncing, only commits new to your master will be detected as 'to be merged'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718540/761202)

Comment: In Git, `revert` and `reset` mean two completely different things. I think it would help if you [understood the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8358035/184546) and updated your question accordingly. Are you really trying to reset, or are you just trying to undo (revert) a specific set of commits in the middle of the branch?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove commits from master using a separate branch. Branches are meant for adding commits on the tip of master — that is why your `git merge` does not work.

Since you do not have permission to force-push directly to master, you would have to create revert commits on a separate branch and merge them in.

```sh
git revert COMMIT_HASH_1 COMMIT_HASH_2
```

This will add a new commit that reverses the changes made in the commits you specify. You can then merge this back into master.

Without permission to force-push directly to master, I believe this would be your best bet. Force pushing to master is usually disabled to prevent exactly what you are trying to do — rewrite history.

Comment: `Without permission to force-push directly to master` it is worth reinforcing in the answer that even if it were possible to force push, that would be abnormal, problematic, not recommended etc. and reverting is the absolutely-normal action to take. It's not a compromise to revert, it's the primary choice with very (very) few circumstances where that wouldn't be the answer.

Comment: @Ali really appreciate the great explanation you gave around it. Is there a way I can revert back to a commit which is ~ 70 commits before what I currently have? Instead of specifying hashes for each one of them?

Comment: [The answer AD7six linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit/21718540#21718540) shows how to specify a range of commits and other nuances of the revert command.