# Reverting fails in Git

Tags: git

```
C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app [master ↑2 +10 ~1 -0 !]> git log
commit 2acfb51145022013be9cf65aa6bb154aaadc947e (HEAD -> master)
Merge: 428c94aad9 5cf5a6a5e5
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Jan 6 20:50:52 2024 -0600

    Fix merge conflict

commit 5cf5a6a5e57f9aa6cb328c55e8eafa03169afe87 (origin/temp, temp)
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Jan 6 20:34:23 2024 -0600

    Show namd properties withot interfering with the main window layout

commit 428c94aad9789b9d5d57b51b13f63f4249c667e8 (origin/master)
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Jan 4 21:06:11 2024 -0600

    Implement showing the and properties dialog

commit ba923f75a327cd5e8e505ef87db29a1d1405511b
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 1 23:37:21 2024 -0600

    Fix layout when switching query sources

commit 715a40549b907aa98480a17fd84ee95eab67c37f
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 1 17:43:01 2024 -0600

    Fix sizing of the child window

commit cbfcc99ecc49ef5e44a76385384ba37f739c7a29
Author: oneeyeman1 <ikorot01@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jan 1 14:40:34 2024 -0600
```

Above is the tip of my GitHub.

In the temp branch I fixed a breakage, but unfortunately I didn't properly merge it.

So what I was thinking is to revert the last 2 commits/merges and merge the temp branch into master fixing the issue.

However,

```
C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app [master ↑2 +10 ~6 -0 !]> git revert 2acfb51145022013be9cf65aa6bb154aaadc9
47e
error: commit 2acfb51145022013be9cf65aa6bb154aaadc947e is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: revert failed
```

The idea was to go down to ba923f75a327cd5e8e505ef87db29a1d1405511b and then merge the temp branch.

What is the best course of action here?

EDT:

```
C:\Users\Igor\OneDrive\Documents\dbhandler_app [master ↑2 +10 ~1 -0 !]> git log --oneline --graph --all
*   7b3551a887 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 2acfb51145 Fix merge conflict
|\
| * 8af2a04c42 index on master: 2acfb51145 Fix merge conflict
|/
*   2acfb51145 (HEAD -> master) Fix merge conflict
|\
| * 5cf5a6a5e5 (origin/temp, temp) Show namd properties withot interfering with the main window layout
* | 428c94aad9 (origin/master) Implement showing the and properties dialog
|/
* ba923f75a3 Fix layout when switching query sources
* 715a40549b Fix sizing of the child window
* cbfcc99ecc Fix toolbar positions for Query View
* a116db0ad0 Fix linking error on MSW
*   16e0535a3d Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
|\
| * ae84555e6b Toolbars shouldn't be inside the sizer
* | 42370bac78 Fix linking on Linux/GTK
|/
* 9926b238a7 Adding the possibility to include any shape for the context menu
* aa6b0f9531 Fix OSX build after previous changes
*   329b272a7e Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
|\
| * 1fa1d63153 Move the color combo box to the helper library
* | b5a2be8c75 Break library dependency
* | 26beb9318b Reset project settings back
|/
* d89958906a Fix typo on the included directory
* 805b9ebec8 Adding the header file
* 58fabe6adf Adding PerMontorv2 Manifest to the build
* 28d50c8bfd Move colorcombobox to helper library
* aea5cc72af Update the icon properly
* 0611dbe847 Fix font name icon
*   9041d12858 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
|\
| *   65aaf6de0e Fix merge conflict
| |\
| | * 08de8c4dc6 Handle hiding the view toolbar
| | * 6d589ac388 No changes, just remove commented code
| | * 4eb52a80c3 No changes, just remove commented code
| | * b611484f74 Fix child frame position on OSX
| | * 98962b6dd7 Fixes for new icon on OSX
| | *   b17ac4e103 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
| | |\
| | * \   59acc5623e Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
| | |\ \
| | * | | 593da40430 REmove unneeded code
| * | | | 25f39090df Show or hide the toolbar depending on the option settings
* | | | | 8e2f72ee94 Make the SVG commenttext display text
* | | | | d6dd1221ea Trying to update the icon to display the text
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
* | | | 3292a31cba Fix GTK build afte latest changes
|/ / /
* | | 8a09ee904a Update windows build with new icons
* | | dfdf8ec71f Add icon for vertical toolbar for font name/size
* | |   454e23a1ab Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
|\ \ \
| * | | 708ad3ce56 Restore quick select query view populatiion; prepare the code to lay out chldren correctly
| | |/
| |/|
| * | fa18eccc36 Remove unneeded code
* | | a49c92e37b Adding the icont for the vertical toolbar
|/ /
* | c4207a35dc Adding new icons to GTK build
|/
* 1f460f231a Add new icons to Mac/Xcode build
* ca29dd458e Fix non-MSW compilation error
*   0d9679c86c Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
|\
| * 3be86b27e0 Adding alignment icons
| * d312c49806 Double-click should close dialog only when in table view
| * 13956ad96b Fix crashing on closng view; fix some layout issues
| * 173c2e6c54 Add double click event to select the table
| * 975abd7ff9 Addng helpers library
* | 07b2e307a1 Remove OSX condition
|/
* f82cc373a8 Remove remnants of old view
* 56b76f7812 Trying to properly add the control to the sizer; also fix the unused variuable warning and the crash on too
lbar creation
* d7ae3038a1 Fix IsNullAllowed table property
* 064712ab1a No changes - just remove the comments
* 493650c836 Fix the parent window for the toolbar on GTK
* 46ccd7b673 Fix the library name on Linux
* afef929020 The defines are MSW-specific
* 87530866e7 Adding new files to the build on Linux
* f2394fa1ee Create a table create/modify view laout and use helpers library
* 7f76291e1f Trying to add a custom control library
*   f4c0261edd Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
|\
| * 2506dba848 Remove build files for the helper library
| *   aedb65c0f4 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
| |\
| * \   0e0d003792 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
| |\ \
| * | | 6d638cac8c Revert "Remove the extra id so the menu can work"
* | | | cd8823c7bd Set the window title apropriately
| |_|/
|/| |
* | | 63aafc4576 Fix the toolbar parent for *nix/GTK
* | | d76e2d9f11 Fix Linux compilation
* | | 654ece6b20 Remove build files from trackiing
* | | 8620e62e74 Fix library type
* | | 879dace2db Fix adding the new library
| |/
|/|
* |   67fcdbd95a Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
|\ \
| |/
| *   91e3a2ab79 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
| |\
| * | d64128ab04 Remove the extra id so the menu can work
* | | 27f8b13d39 Fix merge with the dataaseview.cpp file
| |/
|/|
* |   887406fe33 Merging the new library for MSW build
|\ \
| |/
| *   68d1989f58 Merging the code
| |\
| | *   b8b1d4ef19 Merge branch 'master' of github.com:oneeyeman1/dbhandler
| | |\
| | * | dea69f96e6 Fix code formatting
| | * | cf5a8f386b Adding helper classes library
| | * | fc93ac7650 Use proper parent for the toolbar on all 3 majpr platforms
| | * | b4b812c1c2 Request the library to be created before proceeding
| * | | 0ae19a3935 Pass the data
| * | | 458e1a9f2d Use style bar initialization data to create a style bar
| * | | c1e5c40b1d Pass the style bar data
| * | | bea3534fe6 Read the configuration data for the style toolbar
| * | | 30e8098ee2 Adding helper classes library to OSX build
| |/ /
* | | 8653636be5 Add helpers library to soltion and use it for type combo box
* | | 0b5af9b27a Fix toolbar positioning in the view
* | | 71ea76d5c7 Prepare for transitioning the code to the different library
* | | 38d0b0c731 Unify the code for all platform
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git)

Comment: @Brian61354270, what is the difference between `git reset` and `git revert`? AFAIIU the both do the same thing... Thx

Comment: They're very different commands. See [What's the difference between Git Revert, Checkout and Reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8358035/11082165). TL;DR: `git reset` is for restoring HEAD to some old commit. `git revert` is for creating _new_ commits that logically "undo" some previous commits.

Comment: @Brian61354270, also can I do `git revert` 2 times in a row or I will have to commit in between?

Comment: @Brian61354270, so I should do `git reset ba923f75a327cd5e8e505ef87db29a1d1405511b` to make the master points to that commit?

Comment: it's important to know when going back in time if you want the most recent changes or not A) `revert` will keep them in the history, but with an "undo" commit stacked on top, while B) `reset` et al. will remove them from the chain, either permanently or _staged_

Comment: @ti7, no I don't want those - I want to merge temp into the commit above...

Comment: that could represent quite a lot of lost data - as a first step, you might zip the whole respository for safe keeping, then make a new branch too to save your state - I'll make an Answer

Comment: @Igor That's correct if you indeed want to move `master` back to `ba923f7`. We can't tell for sure whether that is what you want to do without more information about the history (a linear log doesn't show much).  Can you provide the output of `git log --oneline --graph --all`?

Comment: @Brian61354270, output added.

Comment: "commit 2acfb51145022013be9cf65aa6bb154aaadc947e is a merge but no -m option was given." you must provide the `-m` option if you want to revert a merge commit

Comment: @Brian61354270, after doing `git reset ba923f75a327cd5e8e505ef87db29a1d1405511b && git merge temp` and then rebuilding everything it looks like I have a working code.. Thank you everybody. Now all I need is   `git push`, right?

Answer (score 1):

As a precaution against data loss, I always recommend starting by saving your work, at least making a new zip file is sufficient in the majority of cases (though beware it won't save some filesystem permissions, which can be relevant)

As you're using Windows, you can just navigate up outside of the repository in the filesystem, right click on the Folder and choose create Zip Archive or similar

---

That said, you can now go back in time (wow) - start by doing a little more data saving - make a new branch `git checkout -b 2024-01-07_backup`

Then back to your original branch `git checkout -`

Then you can go ahead and undo the commits (they'll be saved in your other branch and in the zip file)

`git reset --soft ba923f75a327cd5e8e505ef87db29a1d1405511b`

Take a look at what you have saved (`git diff --cached`), and if you're confident you don't need it, drop it or `stash` it for later

Then you can merge your older "temp branch" back in

---

```bash
git checkout -b 2024-01-07_backup
git checkout -
git reset --soft ba923f75a327cd5e8e505ef87db29a1d1405511b
git stash

git merge "whatever you called you temp branch"
```

Comment: To add on the above flow, `git merge <temp-branch>` may be good to maintain existing history which is a good practice, but just in case older branch commits were irrelevant, going back with `git reset <temp-branch>` may be a better option, using `--hard` flag with it if any local changes diffing the reset changes isn't locally intended.
TL;DR - git reset works with branches as well, `merge` at last may be replaced by a branch based reset instead

Comment: indeed (though a direct shortcut, `--hard` will result in the destruction of the intermediate commits!) .. it may also be possible to bring the temp branch _forward_ with `rebase`, but I'd again do that in a new branch based off the temp branch with some shape like  `git checkout temp ; git checkout -b temp2 ; git rebase "target branch to merge it into"`