# Merging 2 git repositories

Tags: git, git-merge

I have two `git repositories` -

- One - with directory structure `src/com/yadavvi/stringsearch`
- Two - with directory structure `src/com/yadavvi/prettyprint`, `src/com/yadavvi/tree`, `src/com/yadavvi/treewoq`.

I want to merge both these repositories into a single repository ***One***, such that the final directory structure of the resulting repo would be -

> src/com/yadavvi/stringsearch 
>   src/com/yadavvi/prettyprint 
>   src/com/yadavvi/tree 
>   src/com/yadavvi/treewoq

However, I get to see only `src/com/yadavvi/stringsearch` and others are visible ONLY in the commit history.

I followed [this](https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/), [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) and [this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html) tutorials for merging two repos, but the output that I get is somewhat like this -

[image: History as shown in gitk]

Here is my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/yadavvi91/AlgosInJava) when I pushed it.

Comment: What don't you like about the resulting merged repository?  At first glance the output seems just what you would want.

Comment: @antlersoft I only see `src/com/yadavvi/stringsearch` not the others like ` src/com/yadavvi/prettyprint` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your merge commit deleted everything that was not under stringsearch. You need to reset to a commit before the merge and try again.  Use --no-commit on the merge command and make sure the index contains all the files from the other branch before you commit the merge.

Comment: I did a hard reset as mentioned [here]  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4372501) and got the original repository. Then again I followed the same procedures given [here]  (https://help.github.com/articles/about-git-subtree-merges/) with `git merge -s ours --no-commit PrettyPrintTree/master` and then with `git read-tree --prefix=/ -u PrettyPrintTree/master` and it seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

For such a scenario one might want to give [git-import](https://github.com/CNG/dotfiles/blob/master/mods-available/git/functions/git-import) a try.

It basically creates patches from one repo and applies them to another while keeping history.

Answer (score 0):

first check branch with using `git branch`
then change branch whrere you want to merge `branch chekout <branch name>`
then merge with existing branch `branch merge <branch name>`

it will work