# Can I "boot out" a published git commit?

Tags: git

Say in my develop branch, I have the following published (pushed) commits

```
aaa2345
bad4567
ccc7890
```

Later I realize bad4567 has issue and I want to "delete" it from the develop branch. What git commands to use to achieve the develop will become

```
aaa2345
ccc7890
```

And if `aaa2345` depends on `bad4567`, is such delete even possible?

Comment: see git reset https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Comment: Also, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4372501/1566634

Comment: you can use `git rebase -i` and delete the unwanted commit. There may be conflicts to resolve .