# Can I revert a single published file in Git?

Tags: git

If I have a file `code/main.js` and it has three published version

```
aa1234
bb5678
cc7890
```

Now that I want to revert the commit `bb5678` and make the file contains changes in `aa1234` plus `cc7890`. Is this possible in git? What command should I use?

Comment: How is this different from your [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66056149/can-i-boot-out-a-published-git-commit)?

Comment: Have you tried using `git revert bb5678`?

Comment: @mkrieger1..this question is about a single file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could revert the commit `bb5678` with `-n` (no commit) option, then restore all other files except `code/main.js`, and then do a commit:

```
git revert -n bb5678
git status
```

take note of any changed files, then checkout all the files listed by git status, except the one you want to revert

```
git checkout foo bar
git commit
```