# Somehow managed to push a different repository onto Github

Tags: git, github

Okay, so I accidentally put the wrong remote URL into one of my git projects and so managed to post a whole bunch of completely wrong commits to a github repository. I need to revert the entire repository back to a specific version, getting rid of everything that was committed after a certain revision.

Is there an easy way to do this, ideally without having to touch my original project?

Note that we're talking about 6 separate commits here, all of which I need to get rid of completely. This includes getting rid of a whole chunk of files which were committed to the repository and which overwrote the directory that used to be there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Comment: *Slightly* different because I had to go back to a specific version rather than just the most recent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git reset --hard [REVISION] && git push --force`