# cannot use git rebase -i

Tags: git, git-rebase

On question: [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

I can't to use same solution on my project.

I want to go to commit 30735f3d by command:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2


*   823da1cf7976466da40a5720191d09b080e046d6 Merge branch 'hotfix#1-issue
|\  
| * 71b732ef9ecbf36153ab2729cc78bc522341399e fixed: changed salary type f
|/  
*   be87e784da99fbad8b575b5433bb33a35954064c Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| *   90b23296a3a6c2883f2c434947da4896d8afef5c Merge branch 'issue#2240' 
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 947b43b12763acbd0ca2733f0fd88e3882c086ab issue#2240:create user class
|/  
*   30735f3d4884c4156a070f75dbc5ae3608f9c312 Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * 88b06701fc4a66511da3096b2383c8c26ea2e203 added field salaryDefault,bo
| * d364b0b381ed099e48b614955996696dbe39bba4 added entity start salary
|/  
*   4de63ced11d978e10f5c81cc23e743fbe06ea9cc Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * f16c849b25028a376dbdf03b5d0aaee0b3966d74 setup persistence
|/  
* cb88a650a26905d6a911706bda609162338c57ed init
```

after rebase some of above commits that remain e.g. fixed: changed salary type f, issue#2240:create user class

```
* 12f20a44e3ea7eaf34ca62fb6a7a51f5729bcba1 fixed: changed salary type from int t
* 947b43b12763acbd0ca2733f0fd88e3882c086ab issue#2240:create user class
*   30735f3d4884c4156a070f75dbc5ae3608f9c312 Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * 88b06701fc4a66511da3096b2383c8c26ea2e203 added field salaryDefault,bonus,tax
| * d364b0b381ed099e48b614955996696dbe39bba4 added entity start salary
|/  
*   4de63ced11d978e10f5c81cc23e743fbe06ea9cc Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * f16c849b25028a376dbdf03b5d0aaee0b3966d74 setup persistence
|/  
* cb88a650a26905d6a911706bda609162338c57ed init
```

But i want a result like this:

```
*   30735f3d4884c4156a070f75dbc5ae3608f9c312 Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * 88b06701fc4a66511da3096b2383c8c26ea2e203 added field salaryDefault,bonus,tax
| * d364b0b381ed099e48b614955996696dbe39bba4 added entity start salary
|/  
*   4de63ced11d978e10f5c81cc23e743fbe06ea9cc Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| * f16c849b25028a376dbdf03b5d0aaee0b3966d74 setup persistence
|/  
* cb88a650a26905d6a911706bda609162338c57ed init
```

And now i have only branch master.
Or that's about --no-ff or anything else?

Comment: `30735f` is only `HEAD~2` (the second "first" parent). Which commit do you actually want to remove?

Comment: OK i get it but when i use HEAD~2 some of top commits that remain e.g fixed: changed salary type f , issue#2240:create user class

Answer (score 0):

If your example of "the result you want" is actually accurate, do `git reset --hard 30735f3d4884c4156a070f75dbc5ae3608f9c312` and you're there.

Comment: I want to remove commit on origin also

Comment: @user1162226 From the link you gave, run `git push origin +master` after doing the reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the commit that the branch points to you need to reset.

```
git reset --hard 30735f3d4884c4156a070f75dbc5ae3608f9c312
```

However, this will put you "behind" in history when compared to origin. As a result you can't simply push. You have to force push.

git push -f origin

The problem with this is this. If other developers have copies of this branch locally, they will each have to dot he following.

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/<branch>
```

This will get complicated if they have commits locally that they need to preserve, as the command above will mean that they will lose those. **Its generally a bad idea to modify history that has already been shared with others.**

Alternatively, if this is code that other developers already share with you, you may want to use `git-revert' to "undo" all those merge commits after the one want.

```
git revert 823da1cf7976466da40a5720191d09b080e046d6
git revert be87e784da99fbad8b575b5433bb33a35954064c
```

This will create two "revert" commits, which will undo the *changes* that those merge commits made. Making your history look like this.

```
*   ######################################## Revert be87e78 Merge branch 'dev'
*   ######################################## Revert 823da1c Merge branch 'hotfix#1-issue
*   823da1cf7976466da40a5720191d09b080e046d6 Merge branch 'hotfix#1-issue
|\  
| * 71b732ef9ecbf36153ab2729cc78bc522341399e fixed: changed salary type f
|/  
*   be87e784da99fbad8b575b5433bb33a35954064c Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| *   90b23296a3a6c2883f2c434947da4896d8afef5c Merge branch 'issue#2240' 
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 947b43b12763acbd0ca2733f0fd88e3882c086ab issue#2240:create user class
|/  
*   30735f3d4884c4156a070f75dbc5ae3608f9c312 Merge branch 'dev'
```

This you can push, and everyone can pull - it will be the same state of code that existed in  `30735f3d4884c4156a070f75dbc5ae3608f9c312`.

**Important**

If you chose to revert merge commits, be aware of what is actually happening. If you want to re-introduce the changes from the reverted merges, you will need to revert the revert commits. [Read this answer from me to a different question regarding reverting and merge commits.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736564/why-after-merge-does-git-say-already-upto-date-but-differences-between-branch/15737656#15737656)