# Git merge is behaving unexpectedly, possibly due to an accidentally merge/revert from the past

Tags: git

A few months ago, one feature branch, `featureA` was merged into another feature branch, `featureB`, accidentally. A revert was done, deleting the files caused by the accidental merge.

Yesterday, `featureA` was merged into `master`. To keep `featureB` up-to-date, I merge `master` into it on a weekly basis. Today, I am merging `master` into `featureB` and I am noticing something weird. The files that were accidentally merged into `featureB` a few months back are being automatically deleted or incorrectly modified on the merge.

It seems the state of the `featureA` files as they existed from the accidental merge from a few months ago is taking precedence when merging them into `featureB` today.

Why would this happen? What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently answered a similar question dealing with [reverting merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736564/why-after-merge-does-git-say-already-upto-date-but-differences-between-branch/).

No need to go into detail here, that other answer is very detailed.

The long and short of it is that you've merged in a revert commit that negates the very branch you are on. You need to "revert the revert". Reverting creates a commit with a commit message starting with "Reverting". Find that commit and run `git revert <sha1>` on that commit. This will solve your problem.

Comment: One thing I'm noticing, after reverting the revert, is that is seems to be affecting other branches. For example, featureC is now showing content from featureB. Contrary to what I said in my answer, it's possible that featureA was accidentally merged into master and then featureB was created from that master. If that's the case, would a reverting the revert on featureB also affect featureC?

Comment: A revert is just a commit that undoes the changes from a commit or set of commits. Reverting a revert is the same thing, its just that the target is another revert. The effect of a revert will be seen on any branch that commit has been merged to.

Comment: Assuming there hasnt been any rebasing/amending, or cherry-picking since reverting the revert - Run the command `git branch --contains <SHA1>` there the SHA1 is the revert commit, then do it again for the SHA1 of the revert revert. Any branches on the first list have the original revert. Any branches on the second list have the revert-revert. There might be some on list one that aren't on list two, and those will still be missing the rever-revert. There really shouldn't be anything on list two that isnt on list one. If there is, something strange happened in the merges after you revert-revert.

Comment: As it turns out, the original revert was merged into featureC branch. Caused a bit of a panic, but everything's fine now. Thanks again!

Comment: Don't mention it. Just remember that non-fast-forward merges are commits and that the two branches are not *actually* merged. Remember that reverts themselves are commits that can be merged or reverted. Remember that reverts undo content changes and they dont erase commits. Remember those things and it should start becoming a bit less confusing.