# Revert changes made by branch

Tags: git, version-control

Few weeks ago in one of my projects I merged а branch into master. Later I realize that the branch I merged into master has changes that I don't want to be in master. Is it possible to revert the changes in master made by this branch?

Comment: You can reset master's HEAD to the previous commit. -- I would advise against revert in this case.

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16174629/2759108

Comment: downvoting because duplicate and no visible effort of searching for an answer first.

Comment: @MZON Can you revert the changes successful now?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it’s possible. You just need to execute `git revert <commit>` on `master` branch.

Assume your commit history as below for now:

```
  A---B---C mybranch
 /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

If you want to revert the changes from commit `B` by `mybranch`, you can use the command:

```
# On master branch
git revert <commit id for B>
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
  A---B---C mybranch
 /         \
D---E---F---G---H---B' master
```

**Note:** if there has conflict during the revert, you can  modify and save the conflict file(s), and then use `git add .` and `git revert --continue` to finish the revert.