# git merge Already up to date when it is not

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

While working on a project using git and bitbucket.com, there are the following branches:

```
master
development
uat
production
```

When I started the project work I took a git clone of development (thinking naturally that it contained the state of the art code). Months of work later, and now it turns out that the code in production branch (which is currently running in production) has a later version than the code I started with in development branch.

When I attempt to:

```
git checkout development
git merge production
```

it says "Already up to date". When I go:

```
git diff production..development
```

it spits out lots of changes that say production branch has code that is not in development branch. How can I make the production code merge with development code without wiping my months of work?

Comment: See also [Git merge reports “Already up-to-date” though there is a difference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/634546/456814).

Comment: This might also happen if you `fetch` but forget to `pull` the branch  you’re trying to merge into your current branch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may not want to `merge`, but rather to `rebase`.  That is, take the commits you've made, the commits *you* added to branch `development`—the ones that were not there when you first did your `clone`, but are there now—and see what changes each one made in sequence; and apply those changes, again in sequence, on top of branch `production`.

(Some of them will probably not go in cleanly: changes to `production` that are not present in `development` will mean that some, maybe many, of the changes you made need to be modified to fit in.  Worse, changing one of your changes will almost certainly affect more of your changes, so this rebase could be difficult.)

That said... "Up to date" does not mean the code is the same, by any means.  It just means that the *commit graph* shows that there is nothing new to bring in.  That, in turn, implies you (or someone else) already did the merge.  The *tree* attached to the final merge (the result of the merge) is not what you want, but the only thing git can see is that the merge is done.  See [Why after merge does GIT say “Already upto date”, but differences between branches still exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736564/1256452) for an example involving `git revert`, for instance.

Comment: `rebase` says the same thing .. face-desk