# Reverting a merge commit and merging a subset of commits back in later

Tags: git

I have different release branches, let's say

- release_0 (release last year)
- release_1 (release this year)
- release_2 (in development)
- release_3 (in development)

release_2 branch was created a long time ago so it only contains release_0.
release_3 branch was created from release_1.

I had the impression that release_2 should have the code of release_3 so I merged release_3 to release_2.
I was told later that release_2 will go live before release_3 so I reverted the merge commit from release_2 (and pushed the revert commit).
However as release_1 is already on production so I tried to merge the changes of release_1 to release_2 (release_2 is based on release_0). Unfortunately git says that 'Already up to date.'. It is because I merged release_3 to release_2 (which was reverted though) and release_3 already contains release_1.

What can I do in this situation? I read the https://stackoverflow.com/a/15737656/1269572 but it doesn't seem to be a solution as I need to remove the release_3 code from release_2.

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot re-merge a reverted merge, because what you reverted was the _code_, not the merge topology. See, always see, the classic https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt

Comment: Hmm, so in this case release_2 branch cannot be fixed? I mean that I cannot merge the code of release_1 to release_2? The only option is to create a patch file with the changes? I hoped there was a solution as the problem above doesn't seem to be an extra special one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you are trying to put `release_2` into a state that is equivalent to reverting *part* of the merge of `release_3` into it. (So reverting the revert won't work.) This is unfortunately going to be messy unless you go with a clean hard reset of `release_2` to before that merge. I'd consider the hard reset if the following conditions are true:

1. There hasn't been much activity on `release_2` since the undesirable merge of `release_3`.
2. Whatever new commits that you need to keep on `release_2` could be re-written without causing issues.
3. It would be pretty straight forward to communicate to the team that you're resetting `release_2` and you could provide the appropriate `git rebase --onto` command to any developer that has a branch in progress based off of it.

If you can't do the reset, then probably the simplest thing to do would be to make a new commit which represents all the changes on `release_1` that aren't in `release_2` yet and merge it in. (A patch would work too.) Something like this:

```
# On release_2, identify the commit before the merge; let's call it CBM
# Make a temp branch pointing to release_1
git switch -c release_1-contents origin/release_1 --no-track
# Reset soft to point to the merge-base of this branch and CBM
git reset --soft $(git merge-base HEAD CBM)
git commit -m "Squash contents of Release_1 content"
# now merge it into release_2
git switch release_2
git merge release_1-contents # use the commit message to explain what and why
```

**Side Note**: when trying to bring in commits again after a revert, the thing that matters is their commit ID; if you change them you can bring them in again. If there aren't too many commits on `release_1` and you don't mind having duplicate commits in the repo forever, you could re-write them via cherry-picking a range or using `rebase -f` on `release_1` to simply re-write the commit IDs, and then you can merge them in again. If there are many commits though I'd probably lean towards making a single squashed commit instead, as described above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes sense! At least I have two options (reset & cherry-picking), will think which one would be the best option for me.

Comment: @Viktor Note there is a minor difference between cherry-picking the one big squashed commit, and merging in that one commit as I suggested. Functionally the end result should be equivalent, but if you later ever wanted to look back and confirm that the squashed commit was identical to `release_1`, it would be easier with the merge compared to a cherry-pick, since with merge you'll have two commit IDs in your history which you can compare that should be identical. (With cherry-pick you won't have that.) This is possibly more important If there are any conflicts with that merge or cherry-pick.