# how to properly handle GIT branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by X commits

Tags: git, github

P.S: Please note that i have read almost all other related questions about this but it still not working at all.

I have the following issue on `master` branch:

## git status

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

after reading most of the articles here about this case and asking the company i work for, i am not allowed to:

`rebase`

or use

`git fetch origin git reset --hard origin/master`

so i tried:

```
git fetch origin
git pull
```

but i have the same result after doing `git status`

What should i do to fix my `local master` branch exactly?

## my goal:

- not to push because i am on `master`
- get rid of the current commit without affecting `master` branch

Comment: That's not an issue. It's a common occurrence when sharing remotes. A pull won't solve it as you need to push, like the git message says _"use "git push" to publish your local commits"_.

Comment: Do you want to keep the 5 commits you have locally? Or do you want to wipe them and keep in sync with remote master?

Comment: @evolutionxbox this is `master` branch and the i need to cancel the current change, not to push them

Comment: Are these 5 commits you added and now want to remove them? if so, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153486/how-to-delete-the-last-n-commits-on-github-and-locally

Comment: @RoadRunner I want to wipe them and keep in sync with remote master, the most important without affecting master branch

Comment: @JohnD Then do `git reset --hard HEAD~5`. This will rolback 5 commits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete the last n commits on Github and locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153486/how-to-delete-the-last-n-commits-on-github-and-locally)

Comment: Spot on @JoyTerence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To roll back 5 commits locally to keep in sync with remote `master` branch, you can do this:

```sh
git reset --hard HEAD~5
```

Or run `git log` and reset to the HEAD commit of `origin/master`

```sh
git reset --hard <commit id>
```

You could also just reset to `origin/master`

```sh
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: hopefully this is help someone else in the future, better solution that everything else i have read so far.