# What does the "power of" or "caret" character (spacing circumflex accent) mean in git?

Tags: git

I know `^` as a 'power of' character/symbol. According to [ASCII](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/miles/iso8859.html) it's called:

> spacing circumflex accent

In git I see it (well, two of it) used in conjunction with `HEAD` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10153526/5783745)

> `git reset --hard HEAD^^`

I sometimes see `~` too.

Precisely what is the `^` character doing here? That is, how do I interpret its meaning; what is it communicating?

Comment: More commonly known as a [caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret).

Comment: @0x5453 thanks I'll add that term too

Comment: @0x5453 thanks again. I see `<rev>~3 is equivalent to <rev>^^^`. So are the `^`s additive, as in 2 ^ symbols simply means.. well, after reading "HEAD^ means the first immediate parent of the tip of the current branch. HEAD^ is short for HEAD^1, and you can also address HEAD^2 and so on as appropriate." I'm still not sure what it means tbh. I *guess* HEAD^^ and HEAD^2 are the same thing. In practice, I *guess* they somehow mean a merge off a merge. I'll keep reading...

Comment: [`git help revisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemHEADv1510em)