# Delete a commit from github

Tags: git, github, commit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove a commit on github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)
>   [How to delete a 'git commit'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/how-to-delete-a-git-commit)

So I'm trying to remove a commit from github.

It is 3 commits ago and I'm ok if all the changes are lost.

So based on questions from here, I did a

```
git reset --hard <sha-commit-name-to-go-back-to>
git push -f origin HEAD^:master
```

Now it is gone from github as well as in git log.

I then redid my changes and did

```
git add <file I changed>
git commit
git log
```

Everything looks fine.  There's no trace of the old commits.  So I finally did a:

```
git push
```

Now suddenly github has those three commits that I had removed.

What am I doing wrong?  How to I keep the commits from returning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use git rebase process before applying new changes. After rebasing add the new changes and commit.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2

git push origin +master
```

Comment: Thanks!  This seems to have worked.  However digging around in the .git directory I found a bunch of files under log with references to the commit I want to remove.  I also edited those files to remove the reference before doing the git push origin +master.

Comment: @Jistanidiot, most probably you were messing with `git reflog`'s storage. Not too bright idea in fact as `git reflog` has its own ways to manipulate its storage, and you had changes to break something.

Comment: Thanks! I first did a `git reset --hard <commit_number>` then used your commands and it worked like a charm!

Comment: I did `git reset --hard <sha-commit-name-to-go-back-to>` , `git push -f origin HEAD^:master` and then `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and nano editor opens file:  `File: /var/www/html/site-name/.git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo` with options to `pick`, `reword`, `edit` etc.  I don't know what to do...