# Git - A Way of Removing / Reversing a Commit

Tags: git, github

If you are short in time, please skip the following completely-untechnical-irrelevant-3-paragraphs.

I have been fighting with streams of texts on the web for hours, just for understand how to revert a commit, which is laterly found to be unnecessary, unwanted or wrong. There are plenty of intorductory & advanced tutorials/manuals for git, most of which fails to serve a practical guideline when things get complicated on your side. Even the beautiful answers on stackoverflow may become drifting and misleading sometimes, because in the end we are the noobs who try to implement those answers, mostly failing dozens of times and get frustrated from life =/

When these problems are about our lovely, precious projects, it becomes more and more frightening and stressful and git is hell-of-a complicated creature who is not willing to co-operate most of the times, which make things more difficult(!)

So sorry for the long intro and I know it may not be the case for the majority, but for me and alikes, manuals and helps and guides are sometimes helpless and you are on your own with your luck, insight and endurance. That's why, I am not going to ask a question today, but rather answer a possible one after it became my lovely solution to my problem, hoping that it will help you out of your misery =)

---

`Problem`: If you have commited a change in your project but want to revert it, even if there are plenty of ways doing that, this one has shined for me: `git rebase`. It does not matter whether you pushed your change or not, we can revert that commit anyways, but if you have pushed it already, we will need to re-push again to update the master branch on github and I will come back to this later.

Comment: Reverting and removing are not the same: if you revert, you don't lose history, if you remove you alter history. So, what do you want ultimately? Removing altogether is a bad idea if you have other parties fetching/merging your particular branch.

Comment: Please post questions as questions, and answers as answers. You can answer your own question. I have moved the solution to an answer below.

Comment: I agree with you and will be pleased if you edit my entry in due, such that this answer may help people with variety of problems. @MadaraUchiha thank you for your effort.

Comment: @clancularius: I have already edited :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Answer (score 2):

- Step 1: track the order of your unwanted commit --> `git log`
- Step 2: execute rebase to manipulate the commits --> `git rebase -i HEAD~n` , such that 'n = order of unwanted commit'. Example: Replace n with 1 if you want to revert your most recent commit.
- Step 3: you will be introduced with an editor, on which you will have to edit lines on top of the page, those are not preceeded with #. Each line represent a commit in order (most recent commit appears on the top). Choose the commit you want to remove and delete the entire corresponding line. Then press `ctrl+x` on your keyboard, then `'y'` and finally `enter`.
- Step 4: If everything went out smoothly, you are fine, that commit is deleted and you are ready to jump 'Step-9'. But if this is not the case and if you get an error message, then it means there are linked changes among various commits which created dependency among those. That's why you can not remove a commit just like that since it is being depended by another one. First, we have to resolve this conflict.
- Step 5: Since there is an error, `rebase` lets you into the limbo of git, granting you the capability of making changes like changing the paths of files without you being online on any branch. Anyway, at this point, check the status --> `git status`
- Step 6: As you can see, there are `'changes to be committed'` or/and `'unmerged paths'`. You first have to add them one by one, by this command --> `git add any_file_path`
- Step 7: Now it is time to commit. The changes will update another existing commit, that was dependent on the commit you removed. Remember that the error was displayed because of confliction and by commiting the update, the error will be resolved. --> `git commit`
- Step 8: Now, you can check from `git log` that the unwanted commit is deleted. It is time to move on. --> `git rebase --continue`
- Step 9: Execute `git status` and find out whether you need to 'force push'. If you have pushed the unwanted commit before, you will see on 'status' that you are diverged from the 'master/origin'. You can also see that 'origin/master' has more commits than you have now, since you have deleted some just a min ago. Now, it is time to update the master branch on github. If everything is fine on the status (which means you haven't pushed the unwanted commit before) then skip the next step.
- Step 10: In order to update github, just execute a force push. --> `git push origin +master`
- Step 11: Congrats! You accomplished your goal. Now you are freed from an unwanted commit, both on your local repo and on github. From `git status` you can see that you are no longer diverged from 'origin/master' since you are synced and from `git log` you can confirm the death of the unwanted commit. You can also login 'github' and check from there by clicking on 'commits'.

---

That's all for now. I may have made mistakes and will appreciate any correct editing.