# Rollback BitBucket last commit?

Tags: bitbucket

I have committed some changes in BitBucket. How to rollback the commit?
I need to go back to how the system was 2 days ago. How can I do that?

I have tried the following command

```
git push -f
# or
git push --force
```

And I have tried the following link
[Delete last commit in bitbucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836696/delete-last-commit-in-bitbucket)

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you do the `git revert <commit>` as in the link you provided ?

Comment: Yes I did 'git revert' command. But it is now working.

Comment: `git revert` should produce a new commit that just removes desired changes, it won't remove the commit itself.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14836696/210945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
git reset --hard 'commit-name'
```