# github - how to remove commit from branch

Tags: git, github, commit

I have read a lot of questions and answers which could be related to my question, but I can't find an answer. Maybe because I'm not experienced git user. Then I'm sorry and would be grateful for links to answers.

There is a main repo and I forked it to my own. Then I have cloned from my own repo to my own machine and I work on my machine, then I push changes to my repo and create PR to main repo. This is a flow.

On the beginning I have created a new file in code (conf file) and created a commit not related to any branch. I have commited it to my repo and forgot about it. Then I have created new branch, made changes and so on. On the end of my work I have made fetch and pull --rebase from main repo and having everything most up to date I have made a commit to my repo. Then I've push new branch to my repo on git hub.

When I have checked files and changes before PR I have noticed, that my first commit with config file is added to this branch. Guys from my work have told me it is OK. File will be added to main repo, when PR will be merged.

Perfect.

But now I have created new branch and I have new commits and still commit with my config file appears as a commit related to the new branch...

So how can I remove it?

Or maybe I need to wait till QA accept my previous PR and merge it?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github

Comment: Not exactly... I want to remove one commit from my branch and from other branches which I will create...

Comment: If rewriting the history is not a problem, you can do a `git rebase -i SHACODE` (where SHACODE is the SHA code of the commit). Then, just remove the line corresponding to the said commit. Else, you can do a `git revert`, but your commit will still appear in the history.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-writing your history, what you could do is simply **add an extra commit on your master branch which deletes the configuration file**, which if my understanding is correct, is something you only wanted to include in a particular branch.

So, try:

```
git checkout master
git rm --cached <configfile>
git commit -m "Removing the configuration file"
git push origin master
```

From there on, you can branch from master and those branches won't have the configuration file.
This has the nice property that it doesn't affect any already pushed branch's history.