# How to get rid of a particular commit( after being pushed to git hub)

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit

Currently, in one of my branch, I have two commits `commit old` and `commit latest`.  `commit latest` was done after the `commit old`. Now, I want to merge only `commit latest` to the master. I don't want any changes the `commit old` will do. How can I remove a particular selected commit from github? After reading other answers, I found that I cannot do directly from github. I need to first revert back the changes on my local branch and then make a push again? Its confusing me how can I only revert changes of a particular commit and still keep the changes of my latest commit and if I do that what I need to do after it?

I would really appreciate any help or link. I am new to git/github.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github

Comment: I did read this thread before but could understand it. Then I follwed http://wiki.sniping.org/drcs/git/tricks link and now I understand what the person was trying to do. Thanks anyways. :). In the above link the person shows by an example.

Comment: To the given solution the ink you gave, I added `--interactive`. So I did `git rebase --interactive HEAD~3`. This `interactive thing made it very easier. So just deleting a row from there and force pushing it to the branch did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In git if you have a commit - its whole history is part of it. Therefore you cannot merge a single commit, as this implies you merge its whole history, too.

If you do not want the changes of a single commit in the past, the trick is adding another commit on top of the latest one, which is undoing whatever the unwanted commit did. - This can be done with `git revert`.

There is also `git rebase` which is very powerful. But please do not use it until you completely understood how git works. - Otherwise you can break things much too easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can push just `commit latest` (assumes master local branch at `commit latest` and is based on origin/master) by:

```
git checkout -b tmpbranch HEAD~2
git cherry-pick master
git push origin tmpbranch:master
```

One of the best features of git is that there are some many ways to revise local history, before the final push.  What I just listed is just one way.