# checking out git commit. Putting it at top of branch

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Hi guys I have a master branch that has a broken commit at the tip of the branch. The working version is the commit before that.

How can I make the remote repository have the commit before that (C2) as the commit at the tip and delete the broken commit (C3)?

I am using github if that helps too.

current:
C1 - C2 - C3 (tip)

would like to delete C3 (the latest commit).

C1 - C2 (tip)

After I have deleted the latest commit I would like to clear my local git respository and pull the data from my git address again.

I am very confused.

Thanks for the help,

Joe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on github?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

You can

```
git reset --hard C2
```

and then `git pull`. If you prefer, you can 'spell' `C2` symbolically by saying `HEAD^` or `HEAD~1`