# Gerrit: ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/master (no new changes)

Tags: git, gerrit

I made some changes, committed them and pushed the branch to Gerrit (`git push gerrit`). Now my changes don't appear in Gerrit and I assume this is because I pushed the changes manually instead of using [git review](https://github.com/openstack-infra/git-review). When I run `git review` now, Im getting this error:

```
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
To ssh://user@gerrit-host:29418/Project
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/publish/master (no new changes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://user@gerrit-host:29418/Project'
```

How can I tell Gerrit that my changeset needs to be reviewed?

Comment: What does the alias `git review` stand for?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: https://github.com/openstack-infra/git-review

Comment: Easiest fix would be to make a super minor edit (edit a comment or something), amend the commit and retry with the correct command

Comment: using amend will show only those changes on review board which was "amended"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that the commit already in remote branch. That is why no new changes on push. First try to [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github#comment17680230_448929) the commit from remote branch, and then push the commit to review branch.

Comment: Won't this mess with Gerrit's internal database?

Comment: I think the problem is that on remote branch there is already a commit with that changeId you are trying to push to review branch as well. No it wont since this commit with that changeId has not reviewed yet - so no any entry for this in Gerrit database.

Answer (score 8):

you can remove that commit from remote branch or you can do this

```
git commit --amend
```

this will create a new patch

```
git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/your_branch
```

Comment: For me this happened when I pushed the same patch for master and then for a feature brach. The problem was that the two patches had the same change-id so the second push was rejected. After the commit --amend it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `git review` will not submit a branch with no changes. It's basically saying: "since there are no changes in your commit there's no reason to submit... so I won't". Unlike your situation, this has happened to me when there was an error in the previous push.

What I've done in these cases is simply add a minor change (such as adding a blank line) so that gerrit see things as different and then it works.

Another thing you could do (depending on the process your organization uses) is to remove the Change-Id from your change log (using `git commit --amend`) and then run `git review`, thus creating a new review set, essentially staring over as far as Gerrit is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

`git commit --amend` can't resolve several commits, only can push last one to gerrit.

Another resolution is to checkout and use `cherry-pick commitid1 commitid2 commitid3`, then push.

Answer (score -2):

To avoid this error

```
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/develop (no new changes)
```

Just follow these steps

```
git commit --amend # this will create a new patch
git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/your_branch
```