# Reset a remote branch to a previous commit

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree and am still fairly new to git. I was attempting to merge a version together with another to begin working on the next version on its remote branch but it didn't work as I expected. I was able to get back to the commit I wanted by just pulling it to my local, but now it just has a "HEAD" tag while the "origin/[version]" is still about 5 commits up. Is there anyway to force the remote branch to forget everything I have done and track the current commit I am using? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, I just made sure I was in the commit I wanted, then I ran

git push -f origin

no branch name, and it worked.

Comment: So, you're on master, or another branch?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-f` option to push forcefully to remote.

```
git push -f origin <branch-name>
```

Comment: Ok yes I did a hard reset and a push to the version, but should I see the "origin/[version]" move back down the tree? Or will it just change in its current place? Just wondering because it didn't move.

Comment: It should move back down the tree, rather you should not see the commits at all anywhere.

Comment: What does it say when you do `git pull` after you have done this?

Comment: It just pulls back the thing I wanted to delete. Nothing happened to it.

Comment: Try `git push +<branch-name>` after git reset. If this doesnt work try altenratives in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github

Comment: I fixed it, I just left out the branch name and it did what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

in the remote git server cd to .git folder and

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

the above commands removes the latest commit, then push using

```
git push -f
```

In bare repo

Comment: Please explain what this does in plain English.