# Hiding commit from github

Tags: git, api, github

I pushed my code to github not realizing I had my access token in there. Which brings me to two questions

1. Is there anyway to hide a commit?
2. Is it really that bad to have your access token there?

Thank yoou

Comment: Once its pushed it's out there. You can remove it by rewriting history, but there are bots harvesting this automatically. You should invalidate your token.

Comment: Your first question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github

Comment: Invalidate it and create a new one.

Answer (score 5):

> I had my access token in there

OOPs.

You cant hide commits but you can delete them from history.

You should use this tool:

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

It the prefect tool for this kind of task

> #### BFG Repo-Cleaner
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> - Removing Crazy Big Files
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

> In all these examples bfg is an alias for java -jar bfg.jar.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This made me breathe a sigh of relief. @CodeWizard

Comment: There you go! :)