# How to remove commit from history?

Tags: git, github

I'm a solo developer learning Git/hub. There is only one branch in my repo "round-robin". I would like to remove the last two commits from history, as in leave no trace they ever existed. I'd like to remove it from Github.

Once the two most recent commits are removed, I'd like to push my current local source code that is now working.

I've tried a hard reset, it didn't work. I even tried an experiment of deleting the file on github and it still didn't work somehow.

Comment: do you want to remove from git (local repo) or github (remote)?

Comment: @warkentien2 both, I guess, but more so github (remote)

Comment: After your hard reset, use a force push. Then research why this isn't a good idea with a published rep, and an even worse idea when there are multiple developers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Comment: @alex I did this and it worked, but on Github it still shows old changes I want forgotten, in the removed lines highlighted in red. I don't know how to better explain what I mean...

Comment: Post a screenshot or the link to repo if it is public

Comment: @DanielHepper I'll start a new question as it turns out the situation is different than initially thought

Comment: Actually just got it to work

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `--force` flag.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git push --force
```

Note that forcing a push is most likely a bad idea when you are collaborating with other developers.

Comment: I had done this but I think because the local copy contains the mistake, when I push it the next time the remote repo now has back all the wrong history.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Please post the history and mark the commits you want to remove.

Comment: I got it to work, but on github it still shows, where the red lines indicate removals, the old things I want to erase from history.

Comment: If nothing works.. You could download a previous commit to your desktop. Erase everything online and push your local code

Comment: @warkentien2 that's pretty much what I always do anyways. I'm just learning git as lots of jobs require it but it boggles me why a tool that's supposed to increase productivity is so difficult to use and has complexities that usually are detrimental to what the goal is: isn't git supposed to make version control easier?

Comment: @Celeritas I agree. But the problem here is GitHub, not git. That's why some companies are trying to fix this problem, like GitKraken.

Comment: @warkentien2 I took a look and must say GitKraken has an amazing UI. So GitKraken isn't a replacement to Git or Github, but something that sits in between, do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Celeritas there's also a GitHub desktop. It's a UI for managing Git repos. Not sure how exactly they work. Most developers don't use them. But designers love it.