# Reverse last push on Github.

Tags: git, github, push, branch

I have pushed on the wrong branch, I want to push on new branch but I have pushed on the `master` branch. Is there any way to Reverse the last committed push and get the last code and pushed again to the new branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Comment: I don't want to delete my last commit, I want to edit my last commit. 
So how can I do it? 
I just want my last commit work in my local changes. 
Does it possible?

Comment: You mean edit the last commit message?

Comment: No, I mean to say that I want to push my last commit from master to my any local branch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Undo the last commit by **soft reset** from local `master` branch and keep the changes locally (in working tree).

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --soft HEAD~1

$ git log               # make sure the last commit is reverted successfully as you expect.
```

Checkout to a new branch (say, `feature`). Add, Commit, Push to remote branch (`feature` here).

```
$ git checkout -b feature   # checkout new branch with the local changes
$ git status                # see the changed files
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'message'
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Back to local `master` and do **force push** to update the remote master (delete remote master's last commit)

```
$ git checkout master
$ git push -f origin HEAD
```

**N.B:** Force push needed since changing the history of the remote master.

---

**Alternate:** If you don't have force push permission or someone else Pulled the `origin/master` and got your last commit already. Then better you revert the last commit instead reset (history change).

```
$ git checkout master
$ git log                        # copy the last-commi-hash
$ git revert <last-commit-hash>
$ git push origin HEAD           # note, no force push is needed
```

Create a new branch and **cherry-pick** the last commit and push to remote.

```
$ git checkout -b feature
$ git cherry-pick <last-commit-hash>
$ git push origin HEAD
```

Comment: I am in my master branch, where I have pushed my commit. 
I run this command `git reset --soft HEAD~1` but I can't see any files in local changes. 
Where the files gone? 
They are also not in the git log.

Comment: Did you run `git reset --hard "commit id"` before as @Moses Nandwa told?

Comment: `git reflog` will show you the whole history of commands you executed. Just copy your last commit hash and checkout to that commit by `git checkout <last-commit-hash>`. Now follow the answer.

Comment: Its very helpful and it done what I want, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log
```

This will give you a log of all the commits and then `git reset --hard "commit id"` 
This will reset to the given head

Comment: Would it revert the last committed files and get these files into the local changes?

Comment: Does reset delete the commit or does it get files into the local changes?