# How to undo commit and clean working directory?

Tags: git, github

First off, I've looked everywhere for an answer and couldn't find a solution.

I made a commit and pushed a lot of files and directories to my github pages that weren't supposed to be pushed. When I did "git status" I see a lot of untracked directories and files. When I did "git clean -df" it only removed files from the directory that I needed to have on my github pages. Right now, I'm stuck with all these untracked files and a git repo full of unwanted directories. [Untracked Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHjxW.png)

Comment: git clean -xf or git clean -df might help you. Otherwise, manual deletion is always possible through file system utilities.

Comment: "-x" is probably what you're after, along with "-n" to test it beforehand: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

Comment: I've tried -xf and -df and when I do git status, all these untracked files are still showing up.

Comment: `git clean` works from the current directory. `git status` looks at the entire repository. You are in a sub-directory of your repository, which is why all those other files are named `../something`. Go up to the top level before running `git clean`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove all files that should be ignored using

```
git clean -Xf ; git clean -xf
```

Remove the files that are not supposed to be pushed manually using

```
git rm file1 file2 ...
```

Then manually add all files that should be tracked using

```
git add file3 file4
```

If there were confidential information inside the last commit you should use

```
git commit -a --amend 
git push -f origin gh-pages
```

to "update" the last commit you've made and to overwrite it on your GitHub site as well.

Otherwise, you would just commit this and push it just as a normal commit

```
git commit -a
git push origin gh-pages
```

Like this you should be able to remove what you didn't want to be online and to push out what should go there.