# Remove pushed commits and rollback to specific commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-revert

Me and my co-worker working on same repository, and my co-worker did mistake, he edited my files and just pushed.

The problem is that I'm also currently working at same file, so if I pull the commit, it will remove every my works.

Files are binary so I can't edit from the text editor. This is what exactly explain of current situations:

Commit 1. I made some binary files, for example: a.bin, b.bin, c.bin and pushed to master branch as commit [1]

Commit 2. My co-worker pull commit [1] and pushed what he worked as [2]

Commit 3. My co-worker accidentally edited my binary files: a.bin, b.bin, c.bin but he just pushed as commit [3]

Commit 4+: My co-worker just keep pushed..

So what I want is just rollback the commits, back to the old specific commit. I searched about git rebase and git revert, but it seems quite not working to me.

I heard that using merge also work, but I want to my history keep clean!

All I want is get everything back to the old commit, but it keeps saying that you have somekind of unmerged or unstaged files over there and keep fails with it. I just want to override to old files.

How do I solve this?

Comment: What is the exact git commit tree, inside git with the default workflow, git commits have multiple parents

Comment: Is extracting the binaries from commit [1] and commit them on top of the latest commit an option?

Comment: Are you trying to rollback the binary files to the old commit or the entire project (losing your co-worker's commits)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing a `git reset` to the old commit. Then you can do a `git push --force` to update the remote. However this would cause some modifications to your project history and your co-worker might have to clone the repo again rather than pulling. Also if unmerged / unstaged paths appear try doing a `git stash` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Before rollback to the old commit, please make sure your working tree is clean now by `git status`.

Then you can rollback to the specified commit (such as commit 2) by the command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

**Note:** `git reset --hard HEAD~n` will reset the current branch to the `n`th previous commit as HEAD. If you want to reset to commit 3, you can use `git reset --hard HEAD~1`.

So the commit history will look like:

```
Commit 2. My co-worker pull commit [1] and pushed what he worked as [2]
Commit 1. I made some binary files, for example: a.bin, b.bin, c.bin and pushed to master branch as commit [1]
```

To update the changes to remote repo, you can use `git push -f` to force change the remote repo to the specified commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover the binary files from commit [1] with:

```
$ git show SHA1:path/to/file >path/to/file
```

Example, provided the "good" version of the binary files is in commit 7bb43ac:

```
$ git show 7bb43ac:bin/a.bin >bin/a.bin
```

Do the same for all three 3 of them, then commit and push.