# Zsh in iTerm2 completion causing git push error

Tags: git, github, zsh, iterm2, zsh-completion

I am using Zsh with iTerm2 and trying to follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/449070/5236093) to remove a commit that I accidentally pushed to a repo (don't worry, it doesn't have any followers other than me).

Running the command

```
git push -f origin HEAD^:develop
```

causes an error in Zsh

```
error: src refspec HEADER does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxx/yyy.git'
```

There is a file named `HEADER` in this directory, so I am thinking Zsh or iTerm is trying to be smart by doing some completion with `^`.

I did the same push command in Terminal.app (which still uses `/bin/sh`) and it worked.

What is this Zsh/iTerm behavior and how can I control it?

Comment: Have you tried `git push -f origin "HEAD^":develop` (with quotes)

Comment: You could also use `HEAD~` which is equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that zsh is attempting to expand `HEAD^:develop`, which is a valid glob pattern and is accurately matching the HEADER file.

One easy solution is to wrap your params in quotes, which will prevent zsh from being "helpful" and expanding those globbing patterns for you:

```
git push -f origin "HEAD^":develop
```

You can also escape problematic characters (as suggested in the docs for [git-rm](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-rm/1.7.3#_examples)):

```
git push -f origin HEAD\^:develop
```