# How to remove commit on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I followed this link to remove a commit on GitHub:

- [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

And tried this to remove the commit:

```
$ git push -f origin HEAD^:master
```

**But it showed me this error:**

```
error: src refspec HEAD^ does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Let's take a step back.  You are suggesting nuking one (or maybe more) commit from your `master` branch, then force pushing to GitHub.  This can cause problems if the branch is shared by the rest of your team/collaborators.  You may in fact want to use `git revert` here.  Please tell us more background about why you think you need to do this.

Comment: sorry but I ***accidentally*** pushed a commit to GitHub. @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a better understanding of what the command you're trying to use would do.  It does not "delete a commit"; it edits the history of `master` on `origin`, with the intent that the new history won't include the most recent commit.

Or to say it differently, it moves `origin`'s `master` to the commit before the one you currently have checked out - which, if you currently have `master` checked out, and if your local `master` is in sync with `origin`'s `master`, has the effect of removing the most recent commit from the history of `master`.

But the error you're getting indicates that there *is* no commit before the current one.  If you have nothing to move `master` to, then you can't move `master`.

Of course, if what you're trying to do is remove the only commit that's on the remote, the easiest thing is to destroy and re-create the repository.

Now based on all that, you might wonder "then what *is* the command to just delete a commit from the remote?"... Well, there isn't one.  At best you could remove a commit from history - but before you do that, you need to understand the consequences of doing so - and then git might eventually delete the commit in the course of periodic maintenance on the database.

The consequences of editing a branch's history, when that branch has been pushed, are that you will put the repository in a broken state for all other users who share it (if there are any).  They'll get errors trying to do routine operations, and if they do the "obvious" thing to address those errors, it will undo the history edit and put *your* repo in a broken state.  So if there are other users of the repo, you have to coordinate with them in order to do a history edit on the origin.  See the `git rebase` docs under "Recovering from Upstream Rebase" for details.