# How to reset changes in github after certain point

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS 2017 with Github. All developers in our team `sync` their changes to `dev` remote branch. We also have `staging` branch. So whenever we need to deploy new code to `UAT` we merge `dev` branch to `staging` branch and deploy from staging branch.

Today, i accidentally merged `dev` to `staging` and then synced `staging` branch with github. So all changes ended up in remote `staging` branch in github.

[image]

The screen shot below shows history of staging branch. I need to reset all the changes after 6/11/2018 `02f35fec` ( the highlighted in above pic)

I tried `reset` option with hard delete. However that only resets local branch. When try to sync to github it pulls all changes back into local branch from remote branch. (VS does not show anything in outgoing changes).

There is also a revert option, but it does not allow bulk revert

Is there anyway to revert or reset all changes after certain point and push to remote branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Comment: @phd it looks like the suggested solution is for single commit. When i merged `dev` branch to `staging` it pushed all the changes from 6/11/2018 to `staging`. i want to un-commit all the commits after `02f35fec` ( the highlighted in the above pic)

Comment: The solution is the same: `git reset --hard HEAD~XXX` where `XXX` is the number of commits to remote; and then `git push --force origin staging`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2389361/7976758