# How to revert commits to a branch, keeping them in their own branch?

Tags: git

One programmer has erroneously pushed his commits to `devel` branch instead of his own branch. Then he made his own branch and continued to work in it correctly. But `develop` branch appeared to be "contaminated" with wrong unapproved commits.

How to rollback this?

Comment: Maybe `git checkout dev;` `git reset --hard HEAD^`?

Comment: But how will this fix remote?

Comment: Reset local as @Emadpres described, then `git push --force` to the remote. This will overwrite the remote develop with your local one, which has been reset.

Comment: Force push after resetting the `dev` branch to the correct commit (be aware of the implications...). Otherwise, revert the commits (and deal with the mess later on when merging his branch back to `dev`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+commits

Answer (score 1):

First fix the local side as:

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Then push this update to the remote with `--force` as:

```
git push --force
```