# how to remove image in github from commit history

Tags: git, github

I've added my own image in the image folder on myWebsite and put it in github.
Whenever I want to remove this from the github project, everything is fine but in the commits, my private image still exists.
How to remove it completely from the commit history on GitHub.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+file+history

Answer (score 3):

To remove your private image completely from the commit history on Github, you can go through the following steps:

1. Clone the repository to your local machine
2. Find the id of the commit which you want to delete using `git log -n 10`
3. Then run the following command `git rebase -i <commit-id>`

Text editor will open that will list all the commits, each commit is preceded by `pick`

So, manually remove those commits which you want to delete and save the file

[image]

4. Now, push the changes to remote repo using `git push -f origin master`
5. Now check your github repository, that commit should have been deleted

To know more you can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Comment: If we have 2 commit and I want to delete the second commit that is not visible in History, the third commit will be deleted automatically. It is likely that my information will be lost.I want it not to be in history. Actually I have Commit 1, 3 and 2 is deleted.

Comment: @MrJahanbin you want to delete a commit(second commit) that is not visible in history??

Comment: Exactly. And do not delete commit3.

Answer (score -2):

Go to your image folder and open your image. There is Bin icon in right corner. click that bin icon to delete your image.

[image: There is sample image & you can see bin icon here.]

Comment: This will create a new commit and not remove it from the history.

Comment: After you commit image will remove.

Comment: This does not solve the wanted issue as he wants to remove it from the history, not from the HEAD.