# How do I undo the last git commit while preserving changes?

Tags: git, github

I've made a git commit that I haven't pushed yet, but I would like to remove the commit, but keep the changes to my file. How do I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a commit on GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448919/how-can-i-remove-a-commit-on-github)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git reset .
```

Comment: what does the second line do?

Comment: get everything out of the index, no changes to the files.

Comment: It worked without this line: ```git reset .```

Comment: It does work.... only thing is that changes are on index.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to change the commit message, so I guess I got lucky

Comment: If you wanted to modify the commit message you do it like this: `git commit --amend -m "new message"`. No need to move anywhere.